# Renaming Multiple variables sequentially in R

Tags: r, rename

I need to rename hundreds of variables in a dataset and I'm looking for the most efficient way of doing this.  When the raw data is imported, SAS generates generic variable names like "VarX", and in R it's just "VX".  My company is moving from SAS to R, and the old SAS code looked like this `rename var23-var150=NRx1-NRx128;`  This would rename "var23" as "NRx1", then "var24" as "NRx2", and so on.  This was very efficient shorthand in SAS.  I know I can use something like `names(data)[x:y] = c("NRx1","NRx"2,etc)` to read from column x to column y, renaming each variable along the way.  This means that I'd have to write out all NRx variables and that feels like a waste of time.

Theres also another set of variables after the NRx, for which the SAS code looked like this `rename var151-var278=TRx1-TRx128;`.  All in all I have to rename 250 variables and I need an efficient way of writing this code.  I'm pretty new to R, so any hints and shortcuts are appreciated.  Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: You can use `paste0` maybe: `names(data)[x:y] = paste0("NRx", 1:128)` .

Comment: Assuming these variables are storing the same type of data and are related, you should probably reshape to long format rather than encoding data in column names. This paper has a discussion of the sort of formatting that works well in R, pretty similar to SQL https://www.jstatsoft.org/article/view/v059i10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your initial approach works just fine, but rather than typing all the new names out, just create a simple vector of the new desired names:

```
names(data)[x:y] = paste0("NRx", 1:128)
```

You can easily modify what goes in between the `"` and then of course the final number to fit your needs.  The `0` in `paste0` signifies that there is no space in your variable naming.